# Capture request/response message inside a axis2 web service

Tags: web-services, soap, apache-axis

I need to capture the request/response SOAP messages from inside a axis2 web service. How I could do that?

I can capture them from a client webservice but now my requirement is to capture inside the web service, just as the arrive and leave the WS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [axis2 handler](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/08/writing-simple-axis2-handler.html)..Keep it in InFlow to capture request and ay OutFlow for response